# Reset button in search input field using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, search, input, reset

I am trying to create an search field with reset button which would clear text typed by the user. I am wondering how to place X or 'mulitiply' or maybe svg icon, at the right end of the input field and how to handle desired action in AngularJS 1.5.8 directive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p35x4ah/)

```
 <div class="input-prepend-inner pull-left" >
    <input ng-model="search.name"  placeholder="Filter">
         <span> <i class="add-on " ng-click="search.name = ''">X</i></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: It works fine, but problem is that position of X is absolute.  I'd like X to be at the right side of input, no matter of size of window, or even dynamic changes of inpit (ie dynamic width determined by focus)

Comment: you can play around with css and adjust it accordingly